# partial content streaming in android from nodejs api

Tags: android, node.js, html, video-streaming

I recently developed a range-based streaming using the process described [here](http://blog.mrinalpurohit.com/2016/04/17/nodejs-ionic-ios-html5-video/)

I found a strange problem with android devices. The android doesn't send the range bytes in the first request. Here is a snippet of headers sent while requesting the video:

```
connection: 'upgrade',
  host: 'api.somedomain.com',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; GT-I9500 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36',
  accept: '*/*',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
  'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.8',
  'x-requested-with': 'com.ionic.viewapp'
```

Note that there are no range headers present. But after a few seconds more requests are made with headers containing range-request:

```
connection: 'upgrade',
  host: 'api.somedomain.com',
  'user-agent': 'Samsung GT-I9500 stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 4.4.2)',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
  accept: '*/*',
  range: 'bytes=920435-'
```

I don't know why android isn't sending range bytes in the first request! And then how should server react if there is no range header present.